# Usage of [web-apps] for questions about webapps development

Tags: discussion, tags

Some questions tagged [web-apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apps), asking for some JavaScript tools for building webapps have floated:

- [Framework for building REST API in Node.js](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1064/framework-for-building-rest-api-in-node-js)
- [Client-side JavaScript library for an offline-capable single page application?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/801/javascript-framework-for-offline-capable-interface-to-webapp)

Shouldn't we forbid such usage of this tag? If not, what is the difference with [web-development](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-development)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [web-apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apps) tag is for requesting applications that run over the web. The [web-development](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-development) tag is for tools used in web development. The tag wiki seems pretty clear on the web-apps tag (there isn't one yet for the web-development tag). I would just remove it from questions where they got the tagging wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the other tags are already covering what he's looking for: javascript framework, REST API, Node.js, etc. web-development is just the goal but not how you plan to reach it. The other tags already cover very well what the question is about and web-development/apps will only add a vague description of what my goal is (and most likely will not attract enough answerers as most of them has a prefered set of tools depending the language they are building over).